# deleting sharedPreferences in android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I want to delete the various information i have stored as shared preferences. I know i can do it using remove(),  but i m not getting where actually i should use it.

Can anyone tell me where actually i should remove() or clear() with a small code snippet...?

I used the following code to save data.

```
Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString(PREFERENCES_PASS,pwd);
editor.commit();
```

here, pwd is a String that i extracted from EditText.

Comment: I'm not sure about your question, you can clear any where you have a reference to [SharedPreferences.Editor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put it anywhere between your calls to obtain the editor, and calling commit().. So with your code example, you'd put it...

```
Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.remove(PREFERENCES_PASS);
editor.commit();
```

See [this doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#remove%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 1):

```
Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.remove(PREFERENCES_PASS);
editor.commit();
```